# AuthType not allowed / What to change in apache2.conf to allow .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, configuration

I've tried to add a .htaccess (with Basic authentication) but I get a 500 internal server error and the logs says: `/var/www/html/pgr/.htaccess: AuthType not allowed here`
So it's pretty clear whats the problem but I don't know how to fix it in the apache2.conf

I think this is the relevant part (copied from my conf). I already tried to set `AllowOverride` to `AuthConfig` and of course restarted the apache2 server but it still doesn't work. Can someone tell me what I still have to change?

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
</Directory>



#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
```

Comment: Do you have the correct auth module loaded?

Comment: Which one? I'm very inexperienced with apache.

Comment: Search the apache documentation for the `AuthType` directive and it will tell you which module it belongs to

Comment: OK thanks. I'll give it a try later and tell you if it helped. Thanks